# Can I trust the event["requestContext"]["identity"]["cognitoIdentityId"] in an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, web-applications, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have an AWS API Gateway with an AWS_IAM authorizer and Lambda integration. My Web App uses a Cognito User Pool for authentication and a Cognito Identitypool for authorization. The lambda function should access dynamodb on behalf of the user, and data access should be limited to the user's data. I figured out that I can get the users cognitoIdentityId from the event["requestContext"]["identity"]["cognitoIdentityId"], which would allow me to use this information to make sure the uses only gets his data. Can I use the cognitoIdentityId for this use case, or can the users modify the cognitoIdentityId? If the user can do this, the value would not be helpful for access control.

I have searched the internet, and it seems like cognitoIdentityId is set by AWS, which would make the usage safe from my point of view, but I could not find specific information about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the user has no way to modify the `cognitoIdentityId`. That value is coming directly from the API Gateway/Cognito integration. The only way the user would be able to modify that value, would be if you created some sort of custom API Gateway request mapping that mapped user input values directly into that value.